# Low memory crash with 500,000 particles

Tags: particles

On blender im trying to create a 500000 particle simulation.  Before that I made a 15000 particle simulation and it worked but when I leave my computer on and come back itll say blender is using too much memory and ill have to close it.  I also use all eight of my cpu cores, I changed it to six and it stilled crashed.  This is the third time it crashed.  Ive seen videos on youtube of more than a million particles so I dont know why I cant get 500000 particles with my pc.  I use a Alienware Aurora R5 so it should be able to do this probably.  I also close all other programs when I leave the blender to calculate physics.  I also use my gpu as my rendering device. So I have no other idea than to ask here, hopefully someone here knows the answer.

Comment: So what is the question? This reads like a rant.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos "I dont know why I cant get 500000 particles with my pc" - That is their question.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you do not have enough RAM for your scene. This could be cause by the particles, but it also may be something else in your scene. Try a blank scene with a particle system of 500,000 and see if you get the same error. If you don't, you'll need to optimize the other objects in your scene. Either way, a RAM upgrade is generally a good idea when getting into intense 3D arts.

Also, are you rendering on GPU? If so, try switching to CPU. GPU rendering uses VRAM, whereas CPU uses your computer's RAM.

Comment: Well I do have 16 GB RAM so when I get home I'll try CPU and tell you if it works.